# Android. Сохранить данные из GridView в JSON

Tags: java, android, json, gridview

Всем привет. Первый день тут, поэтому буду максимально конкретным.
Создаю приложение для Android. В нём есть две основные активности.

**1.** В первой активности пользователь видит два поля и кнопку. В полях указывает интервал цифр ОТ и ДО, по нажатию кнопки через цикл активность создаёт JSON и заносит значение в базу данных (реализовано!!).

**2.** JSON имеет такой вид, например, если пользователь ввёл 51 и 260:

```
[
{"id":51,"status":0},
{"id":52,"status":0},
...
{"id":260,"status":0}
]
```

При этом:
id - введённый и отображаемый номер, status - это обозначение цвета бекграунда в GridView (0 - коричневый, 1 - зелёный, 2 - оранжевый) (реализовано!!).

**3.** В другой активности этот JSON достаётся из базы SQLite, парсится и отображается в GridView в виде "плиток" (реализовано!!).

**4.** В этой же активности у пользователя есть возможность по одному тапу на плитку задать ей зелёный цвет, ещё по одному тапу - оранжевый. Третий же тап вернёт начальный цвет - коричневый. Таким образом идёт своеобразное выделение необходимых элементов (реализовано!!).

**Требуется**

Сейчас упёрся в проблему как сохранить эти выделения элементов обратно в JSON, уже с новыми статусами, чтобы в дальнейшем обновить эти данные в базе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

**Логика**

Пользователь добавляет произвольное количество плиток по умолчанию одинакового статуса (цвета). Затем редактирует их статус нажатием и сохраняет изменения (можно после каждого тапа, но лучше одним нажатием на кнопку).

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Из этой активности данные сохраняются в базу**

```
package ru.gamletus.mytest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

// добавляет записи из формы в базу данных
public class DB_Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    Button btnAdd;
    EditText etFirst, etLast;
    DB_Helper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.db_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        etFirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirst);
        etLast = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLast);

        dbHelper = new DB_Helper(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        int first = Integer.parseInt(etFirst.getText().toString());
        int last = Integer.parseInt(etLast.getText().toString());

        JSONArray listMain = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj;
        try {
            for (int i = first; i <= last; i++)
                {
                obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("id", i);
                obj.put("status", 0);
                listMain.put(obj);
                }
            }
        catch (JSONException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        String jsonString = listMain.toString();

        contentValues.put(DB_Helper.NUMBER_FIRST, first);
        contentValues.put(DB_Helper.NUMBER_LAST, last);
        contentValues.put(DB_Helper.COLLECTION_LIST, jsonString);

        database.insert(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        dbHelper.close();
        }
    }
```

**В этой активности извлекаются данные из базы по ID записи и парсится JSON**

```
package ru.gamletus.mytest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

// построение плиток по данным из базы
public class Squares_Dynamic_Base extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    int ID;
    int Names_Two_String;
    int Names_Tre_String;
    String Names_Foo_String;
    int numberArray;
    int statusArray;
    int statusClick;
    int statusColor;

    DB_Helper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    GridView gridView;
    MyCustomAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<GridObject> myObjects;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.squares_dynamic_base);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // получение ID из активности для извлечения требуемой записи
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("id_for_base"));

        databaseHelper = new DB_Helper(getApplicationContext());
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        userCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `" + DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE + "` WHERE `_id` = '" + ID + "'", null);
        userCursor.moveToFirst();
        Names_Two_String = userCursor.getInt(userCursor.getColumnIndex("number_first")); // номер первой цифры (в коде не используется)
        Names_Tre_String = userCursor.getInt(userCursor.getColumnIndex("number_last")); // номер последней цифры (в коде не используется)
        Names_Foo_String = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex("collection_list")); // JSON со всеми номерами и статусами

        myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        String str = Names_Foo_String;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        try {
            jsonarray = new JSONArray(str);
            for (int i = 0; i <= jsonarray.length(); i++)
                {
                JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                numberArray = obj.getInt("id");
                statusArray = obj.getInt("status");
                myObjects.add(new GridObject(numberArray, statusArray));
                }
            }
        catch (JSONException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMainB);

        myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);

        gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                switch (myObjects.get(position).getState())
                    {
                    case 0:
                        statusClick = 1;
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        statusClick = 2;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        statusClick = 0;
                    break;
                    }
                myObjects.get(position).setState(statusClick);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

    private class ViewHolder
        {
        TextView text;
        }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private MyCustomAdapter(Context context)
            {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
            GridObject object = myObjects.get(position);
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null)
                {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.squares_dynamic_base_content_text, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextB);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                }
            else
                {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

            holder.text.setText(String.valueOf(object.getName()));

            switch (object.getState())
                {
                case 0:
                    statusColor = 0xFFAF9A8F; // коричневый
                break;
                case 1:
                    statusColor = 0xFF336600; // зелёный
                break;
                case 2:
                    statusColor = 0xFFCC6600; // оранжевый
                break;
                }
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(statusColor);
            return convertView;
            }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
            {
            return myObjects.size();
            }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
            {
            return position;
            }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
            {
            return position;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Объект для предыдущей активности**

```
package ru.gamletus.mytest;

public class GridObject
    {
    private int name;
    private int state;

    public GridObject(int name, int state)
        {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        }

    public int getName()
        {
        return name;
        }

    public void setName(int name)
        {
        this.name = name;
        }

    public int getState()
        {
        return state;
        }

    public void setState(int state)
        {
        this.state = state;
        }
    }
```

Лайот для активности, в которой отображаются плитки это в принципе обычный GridView с TextView. Если требуется, то тоже выложу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант решения задачи сохранения данных из GridView в JSON

**Основное активити (которое отображает плитки)**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

// построение плиток по данным из базы
public class Squares_Dynamic_Base extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    int idBase;
    int statusClick;
    int statusColor;
    String namesCollectionList;

    DB_Helper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    GridView gridView;
    List<GridPost> listGsonJson;
    MyCustomAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.squares_dynamic_base);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        idBase = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("id"));

        databaseHelper = new DB_Helper(getApplicationContext());
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        userCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `" + DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE + "` WHERE `_id` = '" + idBase + "'", null);
        userCursor.moveToFirst();
        namesCollectionList = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Helper.COLLECTION_LIST));

        Type typeToken = new TypeToken<List<GridPost>>(){}.getType();
        listGsonJson = new Gson().fromJson(namesCollectionList, typeToken);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMainB);
        myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);
        gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                switch (listGsonJson.get(position).getStat())
                    {
                    case 0:
                        statusClick = 1;
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        statusClick = 2;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        statusClick = 0;
                    break;
                    }

                listGsonJson.get(position).setStat(statusClick);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                String updatedJson = gson.toJson(listGsonJson);
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(DB_Helper.COLLECTION_LIST, updatedJson);
                db.update(DB_Helper.DATABASE_TABLE, cv, "`_id` = '" + idBase + "'", null); // сохранение изменений в базу
                }
            });
        }

    private class ViewHolder
        {
        TextView text;
        }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private MyCustomAdapter(Context context)
            {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
            GridPost object = listGsonJson.get(position);
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null)
                {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.squares_dynamic_base_content_text, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextB);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                }
            else
                {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

            holder.text.setText(String.valueOf(object.getNumb()));

            switch (object.getStat())
                {
                case 0:
                    statusColor = 0xFFAF9A8F; // коричневый
                break;
                case 1:
                    statusColor = 0xFF336600; // зелёный
                break;
                case 2:
                    statusColor = 0xFFCC6600; // оранжевый
                break;
                }
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(statusColor);
            return convertView;
            }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
            {
            return listGsonJson.size();
            }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
            {
            return position;
            }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
            {
            return position;
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
        {
        super.onDestroy();
        userCursor.close(); // закрываем курсор
        db.close(); // закрываем подключение
        }
    }
```

**И дополнительный файл**

```
public class GridPost
    {
    private int numb;
    private int stat;

    public GridPost(int numb, int stat)
        {
        super();
        this.numb = numb;
        this.stat = stat;
        }

    public int getNumb()
        {
        return numb;
        }

    public int getStat()
        {
        return stat;
        }

    public void setStat(int stat)
        {
        this.stat = stat;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Я не знаю как курсоры работают, но явно в основном потоке. При большом количестве данных приложение вылетит с OOM или c ANR. Надо бы данные асинхронно считывать и только потом обрабатывать. 2. Вложенных классов в данном случае лучше избегать - адаптер и холдер лучше в отдельный файл положить. 3. Передавать контекст в адаптер - плохая идея (возможны утечки) да и он там не нужен - его можно взять в `getView` из `parent` - `parent.getContext()`. Вместо контекста лучше список данных передать. 4. Писать в БД при клике синхронно - чревато лагами. Не факт что вам это нужно вообще. Лучше асинхронно

Comment: Юрий, спасибо большое за информацию и за помощь ещё раз. Пока что это черновик, я как опыта наберусь, то попробую организовать более правильную работу. Сейчас пока даже в терминах не силён ))

Answer (score 3):

1. Работать с `JSON` надо либами. Например гугловым `Gson` пользоваться.
2. В этом случае вы будете работать не с голым `JSON`, но с построенными на его основе `Java`-объектами.
3. С помощью этой же либы можно из изменённых данных получить актуальный `JSON` для записи.

Кратко:

1. Создайте модели данных. В вашем случае две вот так:

```
public class Data {

    List<Field> fields;

    public static class Field {

        public int id;
        public int status;
    }
}
```

2. Во второй активити получите `JSON` из БД и преобразуйте в `Data` так:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
```

3. При нажатиях на кнопки меняйте значения в модели данных, т.е. в переменной `data` как-то так:

```
data.fields.get(0).status = 2;
```

4. Когда надо будет получить JSON со всеми изменениями, то получайте его так:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String updatedJson = gson.toJson(data);
```

Comment: Юрий, если я выложу свой нынешний код, то вы сможете подсказать как ваше предложение применить непосредственно у меня в коде? Не поймите меня не правильно, я не лодырь. Всего пару недель в этой теме, многие вещи понимаю только на практике.

Comment: @Гамлет, Выкладывайте, посмотрю

Comment: Юрий, я свой вопрос подкорректировал - добавил код активностей. Посмотрите, пожалуйста...

Comment: @Гамлет, заменит `ArrayList<GridObject> myObjects` на `Data data`. `GridObject` замените на `Field`. Как-то так. Ну или только `GridObject` замените `Field` и в момент сохранения создайте `Data data`, поместите в него `myObjects` и получайте `JSON`. В любом случае без глобального рефакторинга мало что получится. И имена переменных у вас не очень. Не надо нижних подяёркиваний и начала имён с большой буквы.

Comment: Юрий, я так понимаю первое активити можно вообще не трогать? Все изменения касаются только второго активити? На счёт переменных понял, скорректирую.

Comment: @Гамлет, да, первую можно не трогать

Comment: Юрий, уделите, пожалуйста, мне ещё немного времени. Если можете ткните меня носом где что подправить. Потому, что если я заменяю `ArrayList<GridObject> myObjects` на `Data data` и `GridObject` на `Field` с указанными в основном ответе дополнениями, то у меня далее по коду идёт ошибка, указывающая на `myObjects` (по сути этой переменной теперь не существует). Плюс постоянно ошибка на `Field`. Плюс не совсем пойму нужно ли оставлять участок с циклом и если оставлять, то как его заполнять. В общем подскажите, по возможности, как действовать, чтобы получить результат.

Comment: Вместо `myObject` используйте `data.fields`. Цикл да - не нужен. Класс `Field` дополните геттерами и сеттерами аналогично классу `GridObject`

Comment: Подкорректировал. Все ошибки ушли. Но при запуске активити приложение вылетает с ошибкой `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`. Погуглил, понял что это из-за того, что в GSON передаётся строка, которая является не отдельным объектом JSON, а массивом объектов.

Comment: у меня всё получилось!!!! Сделал сохранение изменения в базу по каждому тапу )) правда не совсем так, как вы описали, но всё равно работает. Кстати, если выложу уже измененный код, то сможете его проверить на правильность? А то хоть всё и работает, но может реализация кривая. Спасибо вам большое за помощь!!

Comment: @Гамлет, прикольное ощущение, да? =) Выкладывайте - посмотрю. Можно даже ответом, раз код рабочий.

Comment: Да, ощущения классные. Другие задачи таких сложностей не вызывали, а эта прям на несколько дней зависла у меня. Основное отличие я использовал `TypeToken`. Там по коду имена изменил, раньше было id, теперь numb, раньше было status, теперь stat

Comment: Ответил ответом )) посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Юрий, здравствуйте. Я столкнулся с ещё одной проблемой, которую заметил у многих кто использует табы и списки. Она не сразу видна глазу, поэтому её не замечают. Но она существует. Описал её [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666625/android-%D0%92-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5), если можете, помогите, пожалуйста.