# В приложении пропал красивый эффект по нажатию на вкладке

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, tab

При создании приложения для Android столкнулся с проблемой. Реализовал вкладки через добавление стандартного активити Tabbed Activity в Android Studio, доработал его в точности также, как указано [в видео на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00LLd7qr9sA)
для того, чтобы по нажатию на вкладку подключался отдельный класс.

В каждой вкладке имеется реализация отображения списков ListView. Всё работает, всё отлично. Но заметил такую проблему, что при тапе на НЕ активную вкладку, она подсвечивается целиком, иногда вообще не подсвечивается. В то время как должен быть красивый эффект как будто волны расходятся в разные стороны (такой эффект хорошо заметен если тапнуть по элементу списка).

Заметил, что такая проблема возникает, если отображаются списки в обеих вкладках. Если же в одной из вкладок отобразить обычный текст или вообще оставить пустым, то всё нормально. Прошу подсказать в чём может быть дело?

[image: как есть и как должно быть]

Comment: Данные для списка не в основном потоке формируются? Если поток занят UI будет вести себя не так, как хочется.

Comment: @woesss, я не силён в терминах, только начал. Имеете ввиду асинхронную загрузку? Таковой точно нет. В основном активити есть метод, который возвращает имя класса первой или второй вкладки (взависимости от того, какой таб активен). А в классах этих вкладок уже стандартным образом реализуется ListView.

Comment: @woesss, я сделал формирование списка через AsyncTask, но результат всё равно аналогичный.

Comment: @Гамлет, проблема может быть во множестве мест. У вас разметка таба своя или системная? Может просто вы на старой версии ОС смотрите и на новых оно всё ОК?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, разметка системная. Она создалась автоматически когда при создании проекта выбрал лайот Tabbed Activity. Чуть-чуть переделал его так, чтобы подгружались отдельные классы, а в них уже списки. Причём данную проблему наблюдал у многих, кто создаёт видео-мануалы. Тестировал на 5 и 6 версии андроида. Что-то с чем-то конфликтует. И главное что это только на неактивной вкладке.

Comment: @Гамлет, судя по описанию проблемы, она может быть даже в исходниках компонента. Предложений как исправить выдвинуть не могу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в исходниках компонента TabLayout?

Comment: @Гамлет, угу. Либо там, либо ищите как и можно ли селекторы свои применять. Если да - то как повторить системный. Может там можно просто через атрибут фона задать `?selectableItemBackground`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хорошо. Спасибо, буду пробовать. Если найду решение, то отпишусь о ней.